# Jquery .each through Divs inside another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, loops

I currently have the following html:

Apologies for edit, I was not paying attention when i wrote this.

```
 <div class ="left">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

I am using the JQuery .each command to iterate through each div using `$('div').each`. Although I only want to iterate through the divs inside the div with the class name 'left'.

I have tried using `$('.left > div').each` but it did not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So, what's the issue?  It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cLLyD/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$.each( $('.left'), function(i, left) {
   $('div', left).each(function() {

   });
})
```

Comment: This is like eating upside down. Not the simplest solution, but it works! :)

Answer (score 9):

Is this what you're lookng for?

```
$('div.left>div').each(function(){ /* do stuff */ });
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MLnBY/

Comment: It works for this example, but it gets more complicated in my (simplified) code. my divs are inside a table if that matters?

Comment: Ah, then remove the `>`. `$('div.left div').each(...);` This will iterate all divs that have an ancestor div with classname=left.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".left").children().each(function(i, elm) {
    alert($(this).html())
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax would be `$(".left > div").each(function(){});` instead of `.each(".left > div")`.

**Update:** Would want to use `$(".left").children().each()`

Comment: Apologies, I was half asleep when I wrote this. I was using it correctly.

Comment: The syntax you posted is what I already had so no, unfortunately :(